# primitives int not accepted in Generic types java

Tags: java

Im trying to defined a generic LinkedList of type int but it throws me a compile errror

```
List<int> I = new LinkedList<int>();
```

Comment: Generics only support object types.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use wrapper classes to do that.

```
  List<Integer> I = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

You can insert an `int` in this linked list as autoboxing will automatically create a `Integer` object out of this `int` and add it to the LinkedList.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a primitive type as a generic type. If you really want to do that, that's what the wrapper classes (`Integer`, `Float`, etc.) are for. You can do it like this:

```
List<Integer> I = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

You will still be able to put `int`s in the list because of autoboxing. If you try to use an `int` in a situation that requires an `Integer`, a new `Integer` will automatically be created with `Integer.valueOf` and used instead.

Also, in Java 7, you can use the diamond operator and just use this:

```
List<Integer> I = new LinkedList<>();
```

There is no advantage to this, except it is faster to type.

Answer (score 1):

This is one reason Java has [primitive wrapper classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class), since you can't use primitives as type arguments. In your case, you need [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html):

```
List<Integer> I = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

In Java 7+ you don't need to reiterate the type parameter:

```
List<Integer> I = new LinkedList<>();
```

See also: [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)